# makefile increase argument value on each target call

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh

Ive make file with the version that I want to increase automatically the patch value every time by one when I run`make pr`

```
TAG = 0.0.1


pr:
    docker build -t $(REGISTRY)/$(APP):$(TAG) .
```

I want to every time that I’ll run `make pr` it will increase the number,
Its ok that only the last number will be increased

Like `make pr`

`TAG = 0.0.2`

After another 8 times

`TAG = 0.0.10`

Another 90

`TAG = 0.0.100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU make you can do:

```
TAG = 0.0.${PR}

-include .pr.mk

PR ?= 0

pr: FORCE
    @echo ${TAG}

.pr.mk:
    @rm -f $@
    @echo "PR=$$(( ${PR} + 1 ))" > $@

FORCE:
.PHONY: FORCE .pr.mk
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a shell variable instead of a Make variable:

```
pr:
    read TAG < nnn; docker build -t $(REGISTRY)/$(APP):0.0.$$TAG; echo $$((TAG+1)) > nnn
```

**EDIT:** this assumes a file named `nnn` that contains "1" initially.

Comment: thanks what is `nnn` when I run it I got error: `/bin/sh: nnn: No such file or directory
`

Comment: when I remove the `read TAG < nnn` I got error: `docker build -t demand.com/extensions/trl:0.0.$TAG; echo $((TAG+1))
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
`